# Dividing an amount proportionately among unequal amounts

Tags: fractions

I have \$100000. I want to divide the amount proportionately to 300 employees.  I want the money divided inversely from the top down. So, the top earner get \$0 and the lowest paid employee(s) get the most.  If there are 10 employees at the lowest pay rate, they all get the same amount. Is there a formula or program I can create to create this?

Comment: Two questions: 1) How is the distribution of ranked enployees? (v.g. Do you have 290 employees at each own ranking and the bottom 10 employees sharing a 291th rank?)  2) By inversely, do you have some pattern? (v.g. lineal, harmonic, geometrical?)

Comment: Distribution is not linear.  There may be 1 that makes 100000 so he gets 0 but there may be 5 that make 50000 and 3 that make 100.  By inversely I mean the highest paid gets no increase and the lowest paid gets the most, going from 0 at the highest salary to the max. amount for the lowest paid.

Comment: Okay, let's say we have tree employees, each one earns respectively `$`100,000 , `$`50,000 and `$`10,000.  Now, you have a $9.000 bonus.  In this simpler problem do you have an idea of how to distribute?  `$`0; `$`3,000; `$`6.000? `$`0; `$`1.500; `$`7.500?  `$`0; `$`4,000; `$`5,000? (each one of these sample distribution has it's own logic)

Comment: Yes I understand what you're saying.  So it cannot be solved linearly?  I would want it linearly if possible.

Comment: Actually the `$`0, `$`4,000, `$`5,000 example is an inverse linear distribution, taking as variable how less each employee has to get the top salary (respectively `$`0, `$`40,000, `$`50,000) and have a direct linear relationship between this variable and how much each one gets.

Comment: You'll get the most sensible results if you open excel, fill column A with the number of people in each income group, fill column C with Ai*Bi and fiddle with column B until SUM(C:C) is exactly \$1000000.

Comment: What is Ai and Bi?

Comment: What if there are 10 making 40,000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to conversation in the comment session, employees are ranked by the salary group and the distribution of the \$100,000 bonus should be distributed inversely.  (If it is proportionally inversely, then top earner will get slightly more than \$0.)

So, let $a_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots,300$ be the salary of each employee, and $A=\max a_i$ be the salary of the top earner.  One posibility is to have an inverse linear distribution using the variable $x_i=A-a_i$, and have each bonus $b_i$  proportional to $x_i$.

In this case we know that $b_i=\alpha x_i$, and that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{300}b_i=100000.$$
Replacing $b_i$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{300}\alpha x_i&=100000 \\
\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{300} x_i&=100000 \\
\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{300} A-a_i&=100000 \\
\alpha\left(\sum_{i=1}^{300} A-\sum_{i=1}^{300}a_i\right)&=100000 \\
\alpha\left(300A-\sum_{i=1}^{300}a_i\right)&=100000
\end{align}
Where $\sum a_i$ is sum of all salaries: the total wage package $W$.  So, from hear we have:
\begin{align}
\alpha(300A-W)&=100000 \\
\alpha&=\frac{100000}{300A-W}
\end{align}
So the bonification of each employee will be:
\begin{align}
b_i &= \alpha x_i\\
b_i &= \frac{100000}{300A-W} x_i\\
b_i &= \frac{100000}{300A-W}(A-a_i)\\
\end{align}

---

If you prefer an inverse proportional distribution, the distribution variable would be $x_i=\frac1{a_i}$.  However in this distribution the top earner will have a part of the bonus (although a smaller part than the other employees).

A fix to this distribution is to make $x_i=\frac1{a_i}-\frac1A$.

---

I have treated each salary independently, however if you have only a few possible salaries you can adopt a different strategy:

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ with $n\ll 300$ be the possible salaries and let's assume that $A_1>A_2>\dots>A_n$ (salaries are ordered).

Let $k_i$ be the number of employees that earn $A_i$.

So the total number of employees are $\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_i=300$ and the total wage package is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_iA_i=W$.

We define the distribution variable $X_i$ with some inverse criteria, v.g. $X_i = A_1-A_i$ (for the lineal distribution), $X_i=\frac1{A_i}$ (for the inverse proportional distribution), $X_i=\frac1{A_i}-\frac1{A_1}$ (for the shifted inverse proportional distribution), $X_i=i-1$ for a ranked distribution, etc.

Let $B_i$ be the bonus for each salary rank, and have it proportional to the distribution variable $B_i=\alpha X_i$

Now, you have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_iB_i=\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_iX_i=100000,$$
so
$$B_i=\alpha X_i=X_i\frac{10000}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_iX_i}.$$

The result of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_iX_i$ (or $\sum_{i=1}^{200}x_i$) depends on your criteria for choosing $X_i$.

Comment: Instead of solving this mathematically you can use Excel, as suggested by @KarolisJuodelė.  So write in cell `A1` the salary $A_1$, in `A2` write $A_2$ etc. In `B1` write how many employees earn $A_1$, same for `B2`, etc. In `C1` write $X_1$ according to the formula, v.g. `=A1-A$1`, if you copy this to `C2` you will have `=A2-A$1`, etc. In `D1` write `=B1*C1`. Copy down the column. Then at `D301` have `=SUM(D1:D300)` and have `C1` set to `=C1*100000/D$301` (copy in the next cells)

Comment: you mean E1 set to C1*10000/d$301 in las sentenece?

Comment: Right.  `E1` set to `=C1*100000/D$300`.

Comment: To play with other distributions of $X_i$ you can write other formulas in `C1:C300` such as `=1/A1`, `=1/A1-1/A$1`, `0` (when dragged `C2` will be set to `1`, `C3` to `2`, etc.), or any arbitrary values.

Comment: when i do this in excel the sum of bonuses (I made a column F) does not equal 100000

Comment: You should create `F1` with `=B1*E1`, then the sum of `F1:F300` should be 100000.  That is because `E1...` contains how much you pay to each employee in that salary group, while `F1...` will be the sum of the payments to that salary group.

Comment: I've rechecked it and it doesn't add up.  It's close but not exact.

Comment: Finally! I had typos in my Excel sheet.  It worked great!